# Kotlin notifyDataSetChanged not work (BaseAdapter with ListView) in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

When using BaseAdapter in ListView, notifyDataSetChanged does not work.

The code is as follows.

```
class AFragment(val mContext: Context, b: ArrayList<CustomData>) : Fragment() {
var a: ArrayList<CustomData> = ArrayList<CustomData>()

init{ 
   a.clear()
   a.addAll(b)
}
```

The follow code is setListView in Fragment ( This code is called by Activity(parents of AFragment)

```
fun setListView(c: ArrayList<CustomData>) {
    a.clear()
    a.addAll(c)
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(a)
}
```

The follow code is CustomAdapter.

```
class CustomerAdapter(val context: Context?, d: ArrayList<CustomData>) : BaseAdapter() {
    var z: ArrayList<CustomData> = d

    fun notifyDataSetChanged(f: ArrayList<CustomData>) {
        z.clear()
        z.addAll(f)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

It also confirmed that the 'notifyDataSetChanged(arrayList)' within the adapter was called normally, and that the context was not null, and that all data had been received.

Why... WHY does not it work...? Help me please..... ;(

!!! The Adapter notifyDataSetChanged not work. So.. ArrayList has been changed but is not reflected in ListView.

```
class CustomAdapter(val context: Context?, arrayList: ArrayList<CustomAdapter>) : BaseAdapter() {
    var mArrayList: ArrayList<CustomAdapter> = arrayTrt

    fun notifyDataSetChanged(arrayList: ArrayList<CustomData>) {
        mArrayList.clear()
        mArrayList.addAll(arrayList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context)....
        return view
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return mArrayList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mArrayList.size
    }

}
```

Comment: You never said what is **not** working. What do you expect to happen that's not happening?

Comment: Holly... notifyDataSetChaged() is not Working... ;( ... The Adapter is not refreshed...!

Comment: Please add the complete code for your Adapter.

Comment: I pasted the adapter

Comment: You have so many different `ArrayList` variables – `mArrayList` in the `Fragment`, `mArrayTrt`, `aArrayList`, `arrayList`, `mArrayList` in the `Adapter` – It's likely that some are getting mixed up, pointing to the same object, clearing one you don't think is being cleared, etc. We're probably going to need a [mcve] to untangle this, including how you're instantiating the `Adapter`, and refreshing it from the `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice that you have a lot of lists. Normally ensure that they come. They all had normal values and to check again. The value that I added is going to go well to the adapter, but the list is still not changed even if I do notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: I've changed the names of the lists to alphabetize more easily.

Comment: Can you add the code for how you are instantiating the adapter and where?

Comment: The Adapter is instantiating in onCreateView. Fragment's context receives from parent activity when createing fragment. 
ex - Fragment fragment = new Fragment(context)

Answer (score 0):

After the ArrayList has changed, you must call notifyDataSetChanged() to update your ListView with the changes. This can be done inside or outside the adapter. So, for
     example:
     public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      //TIP: Don't make this static, that's just a bad idea
         private ArrayList searchArrayList;

```
     private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> initialResults)     
    {
    searchArrayList = initialResults;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
     }

   public void updateResults(ArrayList<Contact> results) {
    searchArrayList = results;
    //Triggers the list update
    notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
 }
```

Comment: I am notifyDataSetChanged inside the adapter. Like updateResult, I'm calling notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayList) and notifyDataSetChanged() inside the adapter.